# Adding text fields dynamically in Meteor without using jquery

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple application form. On click of one button I just need to add text fields and on click of another button, just remove text field dynamically.

How can this be done in meteor without using jQuery as I have seen many blogs that says it is not a good practice to use jQuery with meteor. Can any tell me how can this be achieved without using jQuery.

Comment: Take a look at the autoForm [package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform). There is also a tip for adding fields dynamically in the docs there

Answer (score 4):

You can use a reactive variable and a helper that returns an array based on that reactive variable to construct template-level `{{#each}}` statements.  A good choice for a reactive variable is the Session variable, since it's built into Meteor (you won't need the ReactiveVar package or to set up your own dependencies).

Then, you can use event handlers to update the reactive variable as appropriate.  For example...

```
//client only code
Template.test.onCreated(function() {
  Session.set('inputs', []); // on page load, set this to have no inputs
});

Template.test.helpers({
  inputs: function () {
    return Session.get('inputs'); // reactively watches the Session variable, so when it changes, this result will change and our template will change
  }
});

// Now we'll set up a click handler to add inputs to our array when we   click the "add" button
Template.test.events({
  'click #add-input': function () {
    var inputs = Session.get('inputs');
    var uniqid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); // Give a unique ID so you can pull _this_ input when you click remove
    inputs.push({uniqid: uniqid, value: ""});
    Session.set('inputs', inputs);
  }
});
// We also need handlers for when the inputs themselves are changed / removed
Template.input.events({
  'click .remove-input': function(event) { 
    var uniqid = $(event.currentTarget).attr('uniqid');
    inputs = Session.get('inputs');
    inputs = _.filter(inputs, function(x) { return x.uniqid != uniqid; });
    Session.set('inputs', inputs);
  },
  'change input': function(event) { 
    var $input = $(event.currentTarget);
    var uniqid = $input.attr('uniqid');
    inputs = Session.get('inputs');
    index = inputs.findIndex(function(x) { return x.uniqid == uniqid; });
    inputs[index].value = $input.val();
    Session.set('inputs', inputs);
  }
});
```

Your templates would look something like...

```
<template name="test">
  <button id='add-input'>
    Add Input
  </button>

  {{#each inputs}}
    {{> input}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
<template name='input'>
  <input name='testinput' class='test-input' type='text' uniqid="{{uniqid}}" value="{{value}}">
  <button class='remove-input' uniqid="{{uniqid}}">Remove</button>
</template>
```

As per Ibrahim's comment below, if you want to delete the text fields, you'll need to keep track of the values in the text fields and repopulate them every time you delete an element.  You can see the full work-up in action [here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rh4v2aFGbep3aQhWa).  Note that in order to do this, I cheated and actually did use jQuery, because it was way easier to do it that way (at least for me).

A jQuery-less alternative might involve rigging up the onCreated function to store a reference to each `input` template instance, from which you might be able to pull the necessary information, but per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227164/) there is no way to get all instances of a particular template through the Meteor API, which would be the easiest way to do it without jQuery.

Edit:
MeteorPad no longer exists -- The code above includes handling adding and removing a specific input using the reactive Session variable.  I am now maintaining the current value of the input in the Session variable, and I use this new `value` property to populate the value every time the inputs are re-populated (when the Session variable updates).

You can see that constantly reading stuff off the screen and updating the array of inputs in the Session variable is quite manual and tedious -- which makes me think this is probably not the best way to be doing this.

Comment: This is simply toggling dude... I want the text fields to keep on adding when pressed + . And for each text field, you will - button, which when clicked, it will remove THAT particular text field

Comment: @Avishekgurung I edited the answer to add and selectively remove.  At this point, though, it's probably going to be easier to use jQuery.  There is nothing inherently wrong with using jQuery and meteor -- when people say not to do it, I think they usually mean you should put logic into the template when possible and easy, not eschew it entirely. jQuery is such a part of Meteor that it ships with it, and the built in `template.$` actually returns a jQuery object (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$)

Comment: It deletes the element but somehow the content still exists. [Another guy who used your example](https://forums.meteor.com/t/the-right-way-to-dynamically-add-input-field/9611) has the same error as I do. It would be awesome if you could help us :D

Comment: @IbrahimApachi good catch.  I have updated my response and will post to the Meteor forum you linked to as well (perhaps a bit late).  The short version is you need to pull the data off the page and repopulate it each time. I included the value in the input template and populate that each time an input is destroyed.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: Since Meteorpad is down, any chance you can link or post the code you mention?  I'm particularly interested when you say " if you want to delete the text fields, you'll need to keep track of the values in the text fields and repopulate them every time you delete an element. You can see the full work-up in action here." ('here' being the meteorpad link that no longer exists.

Comment: @CarsonMoore The link to MeteorPad no longer works (since MeteorPad is down).  Are you able to post the source for the "delete text fields" fix that you mention?  I am getting the issue mentioned where removing happens but it retains the previous data.  I'm stuck and not sure how to "keep track of the values in the text fields and repopulate them every time you delete an element".  Any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: @JonnyMD It has been a very long time since I originally answered this, and I haven't really used Meteor at all since then.  Sorry that Meteorpad is down.  That said ... I have updated my answer to include another solution that seems to work for me -- namely, wrapping the input in question in a div and removing that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use session variables. When the button is clicked, set the value of the session variable to what you want. In your template you can show the value of the session variable wherever you need.

Also, jquery is automatically included in meteor. There are definitely places to use jquery in meteor apps. May even be cleaner than using session variables in places. Depends on the situation.