# How do you get all instances of a Template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I know I can get a single template instance by doing `Blaze.getView(node)`. But how can I find all instances of `Template.foo`?

Comment: I am not aware of a Meteor API doing this. How about collecting the instances in [`Template.foo.onCreated`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated) and removing an instance in [`Template.foo.onDestroyed`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed)?

Comment: Thanks, could def do that, but hoping for something I can use in the console of other people's apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we borrow [walkTheDOM](http://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/Traversing-DOM-subtrees-with-a-recursive-walk-the-DOM-function/) from Crockford, we can drop this into the browser console and find all template instances on any page

```
function findAllTemplateInstances(templateName){
  function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
      func(node);
      node = node.firstChild;
      while (node) {
          walkTheDOM(node, func);
          node = node.nextSibling;
      }
  }
  var instances = [];
  walkTheDOM(document.body, function(node) {
    try{
      if (Blaze.getView(node).name === templateName){
        instances.push(Blaze.getView(node).templateInstance());
      }
    } catch(err){
    }
  });
  return _.uniq(instances)
}
```

[image: Example using crater.io]